# Why don't we need ssp for Can 2.0?

Tags: architecture, embedded, can-bus, autosar, automotive

In the Can physical, the can driver supports SSP for Can FD.
So, What is the purpose and mechanical SSP?
why don't SSP support Can normal 2.0?

Comment: Maybe this (https://www.can-cia.org/fileadmin/resources/documents/proceedings/2013_hartwich_v2.pdf) will help. It's done in the data phase on a transmitter side and introduced with CAN-FD. The TDC is usually just needed above 2.5MBit/s.

Comment: That's all, Many thanks! <3